# Metrics for edge detection (ODS, OIS, AP)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, model-evaluation, metric

I have a deep learning model which outputs edge maps and I would like to evaluate the accuracy of the model. Reading some papers I saw that typically the edge detection accuracy is evaluated using three standard measures: Optimal Dataset Scale (ODS), Optimal Image Scale (OIS) and average precision (AP). Also the F-measure of ODS and OIS can be computed.

However I couldn't find anywhere how they are defined and computed from predicted edge maps and ground truth maps (2D images).

Comment: you can find the ODS/OIS code in https://github.com/Walstruzz/edge_eval_python

Comment: Also see https://pdollar.github.io/toolbox/. Referred to in the above link as well.

Answer (score 4):

**ODS & OIS F-scores**

For a short answer, please see [this link](https://answers.opencv.org/question/196702/optimal-dataset-scale-optimal-image-scale-metric/). Longer answer below:

Typically, the edge map outputs will be grayscale images, with pixel values lying between [0,255]. On the other hand, the ground truth will be binary in nature with every pixel either marked as 0 (non-edge) or 1 (edge). So how do you evaluate your output?

In this regard, your task is now to find an optimal threshold that can *binarize* your edge map output. Anything above that threshold (say, 128) will be marked as an edge (1), and everything below that threshold will be marked as a non-edge (0). Once you have binarized your edge maps, you will then be able to compare them with the ground truth to calculate precision, recall, and F-score.

There are two ways of computing this optimal threshold:

- Optimal Dataset Scale: Iterate over all possible threshold-values, and set it as a common threshold for the entire dataset. Whichever threshold gives you the best F-score for the dataset, that becomes your ODS F-score.
- Optimal Image Scale: For each image, calculate the best threshold and corresponding F-score. (Someone can correct me if I'm wrong here -) Average out all the F-scores for all images, and that becomes your OIS F-score.

---

**Average Precision** is [the area under the precision-recall curve](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/2808194.2809481)